# Iterate over click listeners on a button

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I have an ImageView that I've assigned a click listener. I'm trying to figure out how to give that listener a new function depending on where the user is in a loop. For example, the first click will show a TextView, the second click will show another, and the third click will hide both.

```
public void AddOption(View view) {
        int index = 2;

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                // if we are using index 0, set the text to index 1 text and change index to 1
                index = 1;
                findViewById(R.id.pollOption3TextInputLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case 1:
                index = 2;
                findViewById(R.id.pollOption4TextInputLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case 2:
                index = 0;
                findViewById(R.id.pollOption3TextInputLayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.pollOption4TextInputLayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
        }
    }
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What about having a field in your Activity that stores the number of clicks? If you need this more often you can even abstract it out with your own listener implementation.

Comment: keep your index variable out the listener,make sure to manage where to set and reset this index,and everytime the item is clicked,increment this index inside the onClick method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep your index outside your method (simplest way):

```
int index = 0;
public void AddOption(View view) {
    switch (index) {
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom class which implements View.OnClickListener interface. Then add a index integer property to this class, and a setter for changing its value from other classes.

public class CustomClickListener implements View.OnClickListener{

```
    private Integer index;

    public CustomClickListener() {
        this.index = 0;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
         switch (this.index) {
         case 0:
             //Do wat yo want when index is 0
             break;
         case 1:
            //Do wat yo want when index is 1
             break;
         case 2:
            //Do wat yo want when index is 2
             break;
         }
    }

    public void setIndex(Integer index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

}
```

Then, instanciate a property on your activity of your custom click listener class, and set it to your view. After doing that, if you set the index value of this listener wherever you want, when clicking on the view, the index value will have the correct value.

```
public class YourActivityClassWithTheViewAndTheIndex {

    private View yourView;
    private CustomClickListener customClickListener;

      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            this.customClickListener = new CustomClickListener()
            this.yourView.setOnClickListener(this.customClickListener);

            //iterate over the index, or whatever, and set it to the listener
            this.customClickListener.setIndex(3);
        }

}
```

I hope this helps!